# leitura de arquivo Excel com mais de 1 planilha no mesmo arquivo usando C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Neste código eu consigo ler todos os dados da planilha Plan1 que tem o nome de “Dados” do arquivo ”.xls”, mais caso eu tenha mais planilha no mesmo arquivo, como posso ler?.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código para leitura:

```
  static List<Entidade> ObterDadosExcel(string caminhoArquivo)
    {
        OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + caminhoArquivo + "; " + "Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;MAXSCANROWS=0';");
        string commandoSql = "Select * from [Dados$]"; //nome da coluna e Dados

        OleDbCommand comando = new OleDbCommand(commandoSql, connect);
        List<Entidade> ListaDados = new List<Entidade>();
        try
        {
            connect.Open();
            OleDbDataReader rd = comando.ExecuteReader();

            while (rd.Read())
            {
                ListaDados.Add(new Entidade()
                {
                    ID = Convert.ToInt32(rd["ID"]),
                    Nome = rd["NOME"].ToString(),
                    Endereco = rd["ENDERECO"].ToString(),
                    Nascimento = Convert.ToDateTime(rd["NASCIMENTO"]),
                    Valor = Convert.ToDouble(rd["VALOR"])
                });
            }

            if (ListaDados.Count() > 0)
                return ListaDados;
            else
                return null;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Não foi possível ler a planilha do excel");
        }


        finally
        {
            connect.Close();
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: tentou `string commandoSql = "Select * from [Endereco$]"; //nome da coluna e Dados`?

Answer (score 3):

O comando SQL que está a executar no `OleDbCommand` é que "controla" a informação que está a obter nas folhas Excel.

Para ler as outras folhas basta alterar o nome da tabela:

```
// Folha "Endereco"
string commandoSql = "Select * from [Endereco$]";

// Folha "Plan3"
string commandoSql = "Select * from [Plan3$]";
```

Pode, inclusive, criar um método para centralizar a execução de comandos:

```
private OleDbDataReader ExecutaComandoExcel(string strComando)
{
    OleDbDataReader objLeitor = null;

    try
    {
        using(OleDbConnection objConexao = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + caminhoArquivo + "; " + "Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;MAXSCANROWS=0';"))
        {
            using(OleDbCommand objComando = new OleDbCommand(strComando, objConexao))
            {
                objLeitor = objComando.ExecuteReader();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return objLeitor;
}
```